# Console won't load after update to 4.15.2 kernel

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel

I recently updated an Arch linux server (Thinkmate/Supermicro/Matrox MGA video, based on driver loaded) to the 4.15.2 kernel.  This is a rackmount system in a server closet, so I rarely see the console, but recently noticed that the console screen was frozen in the middle of boot messages with the machine otherwise fully functional.  Running dmesg, I ran across this error message:

```
[    2.961194] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.969525] checking generic (dd000000 12c000) vs hw (dd000000 1000000)
[    2.969528] fb: switching to mgag200drmfb from simple
[    2.969566] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    2.970045] [drm:mgag200_driver_load [mgag200]] *ERROR* can't reserve VRAM
[    2.970057] mgag200 0000:09:03.0: Fatal error during GPU init: -6
[    3.007366] systemd-journald[403]: Received request to flush runtime journal
```

lsmod indicates that the mgag200 driver is loaded, but no console video. I'm assuming this must be a problem specific to the Matrox driver, else we would have already heard a lot more about it.  Alternatively, perhaps the video chip on the system failed in a strange way?  This seems unlikely.

Comment: Try with the previous kernel, and if the error will be gone away, please fill a bugreport!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved up upgrading to the 4.15.7 kernel.  First time I've ever had a kernel upgrade cause a failure to load console.